# AWS PowerUserAccess cannot list roles when creating VM, but policy shows it as allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've assigned the policy PowerUserAccess to a group.  The Policy for that is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "NotAction": [
            "iam:*",
            "organizations:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "organizations:DescribeOrganization"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

In the second permission, it appears iam:ListRoles is granted.  However, when I attempt to create a VM, and try to view the roles I'd like to assign to it, I get the message "You do not have permissions to list any IAM roles. Contact your administrator, or check your IAM permissions."

Should I be able to assign a role to an EC2 instance as a power user?  Is there another permission that needs to be granted?

Comment: I think this might be causing the problem: When you sign in as a user, you get a specific set of permissions. However, you don't sign in to a role, but once signed in you can switch to a role. This temporarily sets aside your original user permissions and instead gives you the permissions assigned to the role.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the PowerUserAccess policy does not allow that. You need to include iam:[ListInstanceProfiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListInstanceProfiles.html) to view the IAM roles which can be attached to EC2 instances and iam:[Passrole](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/granting-permission-to-launch-ec2-instances-with-iam-roles-passrole-permission/) to attach the role to instances.